# Sequelize association

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hi I have following three models:

```
User, Account, State
```

and they have following relationship

```
User.hasMany(Account) Account.belongsTo(State)
```

and the select query is

```
User.findOne(
{
    where:{id:123},
    include:[
        {
            model:Account,
            required:false,
            include:[
                {
                    model:State,
                    where:{active:true}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
)
```

I want to return user with accounts having active state and if there is not active account it should return empty account array as account[], but this query does not return even user object if the account state is not active, when I add required:false to State it returns me Account object with state = null, but in this situation I want Account to be ignored but should return User object

Note : The account is optional for User but the active state is required for Account.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please describe more or can share your API response?

Comment: lets say a User has a Account having inactive state i.e. State.active = false. so in this case I want sequelize to return user object with empty account array as
{
  id:123,
 account:[]
}
but it returns null

Comment: what you get now in api call?

Comment: it return null for User object